# "I want to get it finished [with]" - Is there any difference with 'with' or without 'with'?

Tags: sentence-meaning, phrase-usage

> I want to get it finished vs. I want to get it finished **with**.

Any small or big difference could be here?

Comment: _Finished with_ suggests _finished so that I can 'put it behind me' and forget about it_, like a one-off task that is necessary but unpleasant.

Comment: Hi. Kate Bunting. The focus of the question is the function and/or role of 'with'.

Comment: It may have developed by analogy to "get it over with". I think these are best described as idioms; there's no clear meaning of the "with" specifically, but as noted above, "finished with" suggests an activity that someone was eager to no longer have to do.

Comment: You can *be finished with* ice cream (meaning you are no longer going to eat any more of it), but it would be weird to say you are trying to *get the ice cream finished with*.

Comment: You asked about the difference; I told you how adding _with_ changes the meaning.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, you are right. I asked the difference. Is this related to 'toys to play (with)'?

Comment: No, not really. If a young person has finished school for the day, they are probably going back tomorrow, but if they have finished _with_ school, they must be old enough to leave permanently.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get it finished **with**.

This is strange. I have personally never heard anyone use the phrase [finish with](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finish-with) like that. It is not [common usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22want%20to%20get%20it%20finished%20with%22&rlz=1C1CHBF_enCA859CA859&sxsrf=AOaemvJWN0W-u20_-3-hN-FQ4HSnFfwfgA%3A1635248887810&ei=9-p3Yd_wMNef9QPlj5LwCg&ved=0ahUKEwifyM7ogOjzAhXXT30KHeWHBK4Q4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=%22want%20to%20get%20it%20finished%20with%22&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHkoECEEYAVD93gJYy-8CYOi8A2gBcAB4AIABhwGIAdoIkgEDMC45mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz). I recommend you don't use this.

I think you are mixing three different phrases: [finish with](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/finish-with), [get it over with](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/get-sth-over-with), and [be done with it](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20done%20with%20it).

"I want to get it finished" is fine, but still not common enough compared to the other phrases.

[image]

Both

> I want to get it done. *and*
> I want to get it over with.

are better alternatives than "I want to get if finished with".

But note that

> "I want to be finished with it"

is idiomatic.

Comment: Hi, AIQ. I think: get it over(=finished) with. It's interchangeable and I wanted to know the role of 'with'.

Comment: @Brandon I understand. "I want to get it finished **with**" is not - in my opinion - common usage. I'd even go further and say it's incorrect. That's the difference between the two. And they are not interchangeable. See Ngram above.